# Запуск теста в новом браузере

Tags: юнит-тесты, selenium

Всем доброго вечера.

Есть вопрос по Selenium'у.

У меня есть тест клас, в котором находится, например, 4 теста.

Есть

```
[ClassInitialize]
public static void FixtureSetup(TestContext context)
{}
```

в котором происходит логин в систему,

и

```
[TestCleanup]
public void TestTearDown()
{}
```

в котором освобождаются ресурсы.

Сейчас логика роботы такова: запускается браузер, логинится в систему и дальше проходят эти 4 теста и после идет освобождение ресурсов.

Вопрос: можно ли сделать, чтобы каждый тест запускал браузер, логинился и после отработки освобождал ресурсы?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался.

Нужно логику логирования поместить в метод с атрибутом `[TestInitialize]`

Всем спасибо.